# How do I notify Python/Tornado that the client has closed the tab/browser?

Tags: python, connection, chat, tornado

I've been searching for quite a while for a solution about this but no dice.

Edit: I didn't point out that I'm trying to make a chat server. So people log in, their id gets appended to a `users` and a `listeners` list. And they start chatting. But when one of them tries to close the tab or browser the user will never be deleted out of both lists, so he/she stays logged in.

Edit2: I thought that the numbering above was a little confusing so I posted the part in the script as well at the bottom.

So far I've tried the on_connection_close() function (which doesn't ever get fired, I don't know why), the `on_finish()` function (which gets fired every time when a `finish()` is called) so that doesn't fit the bill either.

Now I've come up with a little bit of a solution which involves the `on_finish()` function:

1. Whenever the `UpdateHandler` class' `post()` function gets called then `self.done = 0` is set.
2. Just before the `finish()` function gets fired I set `self.done = 1`.
3. Now the `on_finish()` function gets called and I print `self.done` on the console and it's 1.
4. In the same `on_finish()` function I do an `IF` `self.done = 1` statement, as expected it returns `TRUE` and Tornado's `io_loop.add_timeout` with the parameters `time.time()+3` (so that it sleeps for 3 seconds to make sure if the user navigated to another page within the website or completely went away from the website) and the callback that eventually is going to be called.
5. After the 3 seconds I want to check whether `self.done` still equals 1 or if the user is still on the website then sure enough it will be 0.

btw, every 30 seconds the server finishes the connection and then sends the user a notification to initiate a new connection so that the connection never times out on it's own.
When the client closes the browser and the 30 second long timeout expires then the server tries to send a notification, if the client was still on my website then it would initiate a new connection thus calling the `post()` function in the UpdateHandler class I mentioned above thus setting the variable `self.done` back to 0. (That's why I gave the `io_loop.add_timeout` a margin of 3 seconds.)

Now that that's taken care of I wanted to go ahead and try and see how it works.
I started the server and opened up a browser navigated to the right url and watched how the server responded (by placing a few `print` statements in the script). When the user stays connected I can see that after the post() call (which shows at that time `self.done = 0`) it sleeps for 3 seconds, and then the callback function gets called but this one prints `self.done = 1` which is strange.

I know this is not the most efficient way but it's the only solution I could come up with, which didn't even work as expected.

Conclusion:

I hope someone has a good alternative or maybe even a point in my theory that I missed which breaks the whole thing.
I really would like to know how to let Tornado know that the client closed the browser without waiting for the 30 second timeout to finish.
Maybe with pinging the open connection or something. I looked into `TORNADIO` for a little bit but didn't like it that much. I want to do this in pure Tornado if it's possible of course.

I'll submit the code ASAP, I've been trying for like half an hour looking at 'How to Format' etc. but when I try to submit my edit it gives an error.

- Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
  code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar
  button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click
  the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Why you don't like tornadio and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Because tornadio uses websockets as far as I know which some browsers (mainly the old ones) don't support and the main reason that I don't like it is it also uses flash, I don't know what for precisely, but I never wanted to use flash on my website for anything other than the video players.
As I said in the above post, I want to notify Tornado when the client closes his/her browser so that I can log the user out. That's all.

Comment: You can disallow flash and webscokets in tornadio. Then you will get ready for use protocol, that supports already close connection event. Don't do new bicycles. BTW you can look in tornadio code and look how it closes connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll look into it a little deeper hoping that I didn't see the real solution in front of me. btw do you know why on_connection_close never gets called? I looked into the Tornado code for the definition of finish() in web.py and near the end of the function it calls set_close_callback(Null) which deletes the on_connection_close() callback so it never gets called. Is this the default behavior, is this expected or is it a bug? I use tornado 2.4 but several months ago when I used this script I remember the close() function getting called. I thinks that was an old version.

Comment: I don't know - haven't played around connection close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having this issue for like 5 - 6 days and finally found out what the problem is, well.. not exactly actually but it's solved! I've been searching on the internet but found nothing. I told in the above post that I do remember it working when I tried the same script a couple months ago, but I never mentioned using `nginx` back then. I've been struggling with Apache + mod_proxy but I don't know what the issue is with `apache` but when I tried `nginx` this time again it just worked!

If you have the same issue (on_connection_close not getting fired) "TRY" `nginx`. Thanks for your help too @Nikolay.

Answer (score 0):

There is `on_close()` method of `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` for handling tab/browser close event. Here is an example:

```
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler

class MyWebsocketHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    ...

    def on_close(self):
        self.application.database.abort()
```

and the [reference](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html?highlight=WebSocketHandler#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.on_close) page.